# Date insert into mysql table

Tags: mysql, datetime, date, timestamp

My sql insert was `date(%d-%M-%y)` but that has zero effect on the field no data was added. Neither did inserting `02-Dec-2010`. What do I have to change the table field Type or Default to so that the date inserted will be in 02-Dec-2010 format?

```
Field: creationdate
Type: timestamp 
Default: CURRENT_TIMESTAMP (showing 0000-00-00 00:00:00)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't pre-format your dates. You insert a timestamp formatted like YYYY-MM-DD HH:II:SS and when you need to format your date (SELECT statement), you use [DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/fr/date-and-time-functions.html) function.

If you already have a timestamp like 02-Dec-2010, you can use STR_TO_DATE function to convert it to a real timestamp.

```
mysql> SELECT DATE_FORMAT(current_date, '%d-%b-%Y');
+--------------------------------+
| DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%d-%b-%Y') |
+--------------------------------+
| 02-Dec-2010                    |
+--------------------------------+

mysql> SELECT STR_TO_DATE('02-Dec-2010', '%d-%b-%Y');
+----------------------------------------+
| STR_TO_DATE('02-Dec-2010', '%d-%b-%Y') |
+----------------------------------------+
| 2010-12-02                             |
+----------------------------------------+
```

Comment: so to avoid this I should just set the date field to a regular varchar field and have my sql insert be date(%d-%M-%y). Then I can Select the date in the already present format I want right?

Comment: @acctman : No, you shouldn't. Store your dates in the YYYY-MM-DD format. When you select your dates, then you can use the DATE_FORMAT function.

Comment: so should i leave my current Field at timestamp with the default of current_timestamp? if so how should my mysql query insert look for adding in the date? I tried date(%d-%M-%y) with an insert and nothing was saved in the table.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL expects date / datetime datatypes to contain dates and/or timestamps that have the date in the YYYY-MM-DD format where - is any valid separator. 02-Dec-2010 is not a valid date for those types.

Comment: the spreadsheet data has the date in 01-Dec-2010 format so either i have to use a varchar field type or figure out how to insert that using the date_format

Comment: INSERT INTO (date, something) VALUES (STR_TO_DATE('01-Dec-2010', '%d-%b-%Y'), something );